# Why is the title not being set properly after the instance variable has been created?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to setup a basic example that I can expand upon for my main program. My question here is why does the title not equal "HeyBARK"? I made book a part of the bookTitles class so shouldn't the title being set automatically add the bark?

After this is done I will also need to reference a capitalization method I created in the original assignment. The idea will be once the book title is set like in the snippet below, I will pass that value into the method and set it to equal the return result. How do I access just the title to be modified since the setter method will take in the entire object?

```
class bookTitle {
  constructor(title){
  this.title = title + "BARK";
}

// Everything in comments is part of the second paragraph in the 
// question, I will psuedo code it

// getter the object here to access its title

// use a setter to call my capitalization method to capitalize certain 
// words in the title

// title creator method that returns the modified value, will be called in setter

// cap method that purely caps the correct words, will be called within 
// title creator
}

var book = new bookTitle();
console.log(book); //title is undefinedBARK as expected
book.title = "Hey";
console.log(book); // currently returns Hey, not HeyBARK
```

If it helps I here is the actual code for my current working solution, a nice dev was able to make it work in an isolated environment here the other day but now I am trying to modify this to work in a setter way.

```
titleCreator(string) {
        // Note that this isn't meant to be a fully fledged title creator, just designed to pass these specific tests
        var littleWords = ["and", "over", "the"]; // These are the words that we don't want to capitalize

        var self = this; // doesn't need to be here, just for syntax sugar, using this searches for things inside this class

        var modifiedString = string
        .split(' ') // Splits string into array of words, basically breaks up the sentence
        .map(function(word,index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                return self.capitalize(word); // capitalize the first word of the string
            } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) == -1) {
                return self.capitalize(word); // capitalize any words that are not little, the -1 is returned by indexOf if it can't find the word in the array
            } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
                return word; // do not capitalize as this word is in the list of littleWords
            }
        })
        .join(' '); // Joins every element of an array into a string with a space inbetween each value. Basically you created a sentence from an array of words

        return modifiedString;

    }

    capitalize(word) {
        return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
        // This function just capitalizes the word given to it
    }
```

Comment: Your concatenation is inside a constructor function that is called when you use **new** keyword,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that you misunderstood the constructor concept here. Constructor builds a new instance of given class, in this case you create an instance of BookTitle class. After a new instance is created, constructor doesn't have any power on it, anymore. It's also a good practice to name your classes with capital letters and instances with lowercase.

To achieve, what you want, you need to specify getter and setter for your property, for example:

```js
class BookTitle {
  constructor(title){
    this.title = title;
  }
  
  get title() {
    return this._title ;
  }
  
  set title(title) {
    this._title = title + 'BARK';
  }
}

let bookTitle = new BookTitle();
bookTitle.title = 'test';
console.log(bookTitle.title);
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense now. The constructor merely constructs once, then after that it is all about get and set. The Jasmine test cases I need to pass are written the exact way you just wrote this example so this was of major help thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
book.title = "Hey";
```

this is over writing the value bark in title.
the constructor gets called on creation. so you doing the above line replaces the value and does not recall the constructor.

Comment: It looks like this is where getter and setter functions come in, didn't realize the constructor method was just to create that one instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably specify the title when you are instantiating, so you should use:

```
var book = new bookTitle('Hey');

book === 'Hey Bark'
```

Otherwise, you are resetting the entire title attribute after instantiating, so it ignores how the title is getting set up on initialisation.